# Can't send powershell email to managers

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PS script to email managers about employees with expiring accounts(NOT PASSWORDS) within the next 10 days.
I know this has been discussed already a few times but I was unable to find a suitable solution to this issue.

This is what I have so far:

```
$MyEmail = "email@domain.com"
$SMTP= "domain.com"
$To = "email@domain.com"    
$Subject = "Account expiring"
$Body = "Hi_,

the following account is due to expire, please reply to this email if 
you wish to extend the account for a further 3 months

Kind regards,

Tech Team"

$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Powershell Test 
OU,DC=domain,DC=com" -Properties emailaddress, 
Manager,accountexpirationdate
$Users | Select 
Name,emailaddress,accountexpirationdate,@{label="Manager";expression= . 
{(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties emailaddress).emailaddress}}

 Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject -Body $Body 
-SmtpServer $SMTP
```

I believe I am missing a few pieces.
Can anyone help?
It would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't mention the error you get .

Comment: The formatting of that code would create errors. Is that _exactly_ how you are running your code? For example you have a period after the variable `$to` is declared and a `select` that is broken across two lines and a calculated property that has a extra period in it?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for you reply. I've noticed the full stop ... It was added when I've pasted the content. Also the SELECT is splitted only because it was pasted in that manner, it is actually a one line.

Answer (score 0):

So I've edited my previous comment, because I couldn't stand that is was still not very good:

```
$MyEmail = "email@domain.com"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$SMTP= "domain.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($MyEmail, $secpasswd)

$NeverExpires = 9223372036854775807;
$ExpireMin = (Get-Date).AddDays(0);
$ExpireMax = (Get-Date).AddDays(90);
$today = (Get-Date)

try{
    $expiringsoon = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Powershell Test OU,DC=domain,DC=com" -Properties accountExpires | Where-Object {$_.accountExpires -ne $NeverExpires -and [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($_.accountExpires)) -lt $ExpireMax -and [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($_.accountExpires)) -gt $ExpireMin }
}catch{
    throw $_
}
foreach($user in $expiringsoon){
    try{
        $userDetails = Get-ADUser $user -Properties AccountExpirationDate,accountExpires,manager
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Error while searching for user '$user'" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    $ExpiryDate = $userDetails.AccountExpirationDate
    $DaysLeft = ($ExpiryDate-$today).days
    $DateStr = $ExpiryDate.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    $name = $user.Name
    $manager = $userDetails.manager
    try{
        $managerEmail = (Get-ADUser $manager -Properties emailAddress).emailAddress
        if(!$managerEmail){
            $managerEmail = $MyEmail
        }
    }catch{
        $managerEmail = $MyEmail
    }

    # Set Greeting based on Number of Days to Expiry. 

    # Check Number of Days to Expiry 
    $messageDays = $DaysLeft 

    if (($DaysLeft) -gt "1") 
    { 
        $messageDays = "in " + "$DaysLeft" + " days" 
    } 
    ElseIf (($DaysLeft) -eq "1") 
    { 
        $messageDays = "in 1 day" 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $messageDays = "today"
    } 


   # Email Subject Set Here 
    $subject="The account of $name will expire $messageDays " 

    # Email Body Set Here, Note You can use HTML, including Images. 
    $body =" 
    Hi,
    <p>the following account '$name' is due to expire, please reply to this email if you wish to extend the account for a further 3 months<br>
    <p>Kind regards, <br>
    Tech Team  
    </P>"  

    #----- Show Details of sent mail -----#
    try{
        Send-MailMessage -to $managerEmail -from $MyEmail -SmtpServer $SMTP -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High –Credential $cred -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl
        Write-Host "An e-mail has been send to $managerEmail about $name" -ForegroundColor Green
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Email to $managerEmail for $name failed with error: $($_.exception.message)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Okay, because I couldn't help but wanting to get the script right. Here my present to you. A perfectly working script that sends emails to managers of whom the user expires within 90 days. I also included error handling. Please take this script as a guide to create your own and if you have any questions, feel free.

Comment: Best practice would also not use -Filter * - the following will get accounts that actually have an expiry date: Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -like "*"'

Comment: Hi Bernard, Thank you for you reply. However I don't need it for the expiring passwords.

Comment: This is not for expiring passwords, but expiring accounts. So might still be useful ;)

Comment: Hi Bernard, This has worked like a charm. However I had to remove the SMTPport, we couldn't access the remote server. Brilliant! Thank you very much! Best Regards

Comment: Glad to help! Thanks for letting me know :)